# Remove ActionBar subtitle / Reset ActionBar text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm currently setting the `ActionBar` subtitle on certain pages, but on some pages i don't want to have a subtitle.

I can simply set the text of the subtitle to nothing, but this just removes the text. It still occupies the subtitle space and thus pushes the title up.
It can be hard to explain, so i illustrated with a picture:

[image: Example]

1) This show the `ActionBar` with no subtitle set, which is how i want to be able to set it.

2 This shows the ActionBar with a subtitle set, which is how i want to show it on some pages.

3) And finally, this is how the `ActionBar` looks after i set a subtitle and try to remove it.
As you can see, the title has been pushed up and the subtitle is not gone, it's just not showing anything.

I hope someone can help me out with this, i've tried googling the problem, i've digged through the official android website to find a `getActionBar().ResetSubtitle()` or similar, but so far i've come up empty handed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Call `ActionBar.setSubtitle(null)`, this will change the visibility of the subtitle `TextView` to `View.GONE`.

**Source**

[ActionBarView.setSubtitle](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L525)

Comment: Small typo setSubTitle => setSubtitle. But thanks and +1

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it still remains at the top, it only goes back to the center after a second setSubtitle(null) a few seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `Toolbar` as your activity's `ActionBar`, you need to manually request the `Toolbar` layout its children. Although in theory `Toolbar#requestLayout()` would work, it only worked for me on its parent (`CollapsingToolbarLayout`). I suspect that wouldn't be required if that class wasn't its parent.

You might also investigate `View#forceLayout()` if layout still doesn't occur. For some reason, the automatic layout behaviour would stop in some situations, requiring layout to be requested manually. It can't do much harm to request it again.