# Removing toolbar subtitle

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

How can we properly remove the toolbar's subtitle and put the title back in it's place?

Doing this `getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);` only removes the text but the title remains in the top, [this image represents the behaviour.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGxjn.png)

I've also tried this as an attempt to refresh it, but didn't work aswell:

```
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

XML code:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/settingsToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_padding"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_min_height"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
```

Setting up the toolbar:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.settingsToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709160/remove-actionbar-subtitle-reset-actionbar-text) since the accepted answer does not solve it.

Comment: Solution with "null" works fine for me. Can you post more information? code/toolbar xml.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Setting getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null); working fine for me too.

Comment: I dunno. I use your code and it works fine on 3 devices. May be problem with bottom element's padding. Or with your device.

Comment: Remove padding and check if it works. And why you need to set minHeight ?

Comment: @Tasneem minHeight is to set the toolbar's icons on the right position on API 19<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

If you remove that it will work but it won't have the pretty animation, right now I've settled for this:

```
public void changeSubtitle(@Nullable String subtitle) {

    if (subtitle == null) {
        toolbar.setLayoutTransition(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
    } else {
        toolbar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
    }
}
```

It animates when adding the subtitle, but doesn't when removing.

Answer (score 6):

Just do this:

`toolbar.setSubtitle(null);
toolbar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());`